# NoMethodError when invoking ActionMailer .deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5.1

When trying to invoke .deliver_later to test out functions of ActionMailer using Rails5.1, I am running into an error where it can't seem to find the method.  I was able to make a 'test app' where I was able to get it working using a walkthrough, but integrating it into my current project keeps breaking.

The only major difference between the two projects as I compare them, is scaffolding was used in the one that works, whereas in the one i'm trying to integrate it into it was not.  Below are the contents of the problematic app.

**Trace**

```
app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/mailers/mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:26:in `login'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   action_mailer/base
```

**MyProject/app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def login
        @user = User.find_by('email = ?', params[:user][:email])

        if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
            ##email tester
            UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            session[:user_email] = @user.email
            redirect_to '/'
        else
            flash[:login] = ["Invalid Email or Password"]
            redirect_back(fallback_location: users_signin_path)
        end
    end
end
```

**MyProject/app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' 
/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br>
    </p>

    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MyProject/app/mailers/application_mailer.rb**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

**MyProject/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to MyApp!')
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'geokit-rails'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'filterrific'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'rails-footnotes'
end
```

**app/config/environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.deliver_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'example.com',
    user_name:            'myemail@gmail.com',
    password:             'my_pw_for_gmail_acct',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: Please post your `application_mailer.rb` code.

Comment: Added, thanks for taking the time to look at this :)

Comment: Not sure if this might have something to do with your error, but you should change `config.action_mailer.deliver_method = :smtp` on `config/environments/development.rb` to `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`. 

Also if the mail is going to be sent on the background you probably shouldn't pass the `user` object, instead you should pass the `user_id` and fetch the user from the database on the mailer

Comment: That totally did it, thank you much!  Post as answer so I can uptick you